# C# - Implicitly convert or infer generic return type

Tags: c#, .net

I've started using the pattern of a generic result type as a wrapper object that includes a return value and information about the operation like whether it succeeded. Here's an example:

```
public class Researcher
{
    public Result<string> LearnThing(bool factDesired)
    {
        // Validate and bail if failure
        var validationResult = ValidateIntentions(factDesired);
        if (!validationResult.Succeeded)
        {
            // Ideally: return validationResult directly without converting to new instance
            return Result.Failure<string>(validationResult.Error);
        }

        return StateOpinion();
    }

    public Result<string> StateOpinion()
    {
        return Result.Success("I like turtles");
    }

    public Result<bool> ValidateIntentions(bool factDesired)
    {
        if (factDesired)
        {
            // Ideally: no <bool> required, infer default instead
            return Result.Failure<bool>("Only opinions here, sorry");
        }
        else
        {
            return Result.Success(true);
        }
    }
}

public class Result<T>
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }

    public string Error { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}

// Static helpers
public static class Result
{
    public static Result<T> Success<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Result<T> { Succeeded = true, Value = value };
    }

    public static Result<T> Failure<T>(string error)
    {
        return new Result<T> { Succeeded = false, Error = error };
    }
}
```

Here, the generic `Result<T>` class is used on each method and a static helper class provides a mechanism to create the results with success status implied. So far, this is working nicely.

The one bikeshedding annoyance I have with this approach is that I need to restate the `<T>` often where ideally it could be inferred or when I no longer care about `T Value` (which would be `default`) and only about `Error`, as in the case of failures. I somewhat understand that C# doesn't infer from method return types, but I have come across some mentions of [implicit operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) that seem to allow some [cool tricks](https://tyrrrz.me/blog/return-type-inference) that I don't quite understand.

So, I humbly submit the question to the C# wizards among you: is there some variation or magic I can add to this approach to achieve more type inference and effectively an implicit `Result<"I don't care">` for failure results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exactly the same technique as described [in the article you linked to](https://tyrrrz.me/blog/return-type-inference).

Step 1: You define a non-generic helper class for your Failure case:

```
public class FailureResult
{
    public string Error { get; }
    
    public FailureResult(string error) { Error = error; }
}
```

Step 2: You change your static helper to return a `FailureResult` instead of a `Result<T>`:

```
public static class Result
{
    ...

    public static FailureResult Failure(string error)
    {
        return new FailureResult(error);
    }
}
```

Step 3: You define an implicit conversion from `FailureResult` to `Result<T>`:

```
public class Result<T>
{
    ...

    public static implicit operator Result<T>(FailureResult result) 
    {
        return new Result<T> { Succeeded = false, Error = result.Error };
    }
}
```

Step 4: Profit

```
public Result<bool> ValidateIntentions(bool factDesired)
{
    if (factDesired)
    {
        // No <bool> required!
        return Result.Failure("Only opinions here, sorry");
    }
    else
    {
        return Result.Success(true);
    }
}
```

([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rAySDb))

Comment: Awesome, very clear. Implemented and code now so fresh and clean.

Answer (score 1):

You could get around the `bool` issue with just an overload:

```
public static Result<bool> Failure(string error)
{
   return new Result<bool> { Succeeded = false, Error = error };
}
```

Allowing this:

```
return Result.Failure("Only opinions here, sorry");
```

As for:

```
// Ideally: return validationResult directly without converting to new instance
return Result.Failure<string>(validationResult.Error);
```

You *could* use an implicit operator:

```
public static implicit operator Result<string>(Result<T> result)
{ 
   return Result.Failure<string>(result.Error);
}
```

Which would allow you to do:

```
if (!validationResult.Succeeded)
{
    // Ideally: return validationResult directly without converting to new instance
    return validationResult;
}
```

Though I personally wouldn't do this, it's unexpected and misusing the language feature.

You could however use an instance method or extension method:

```
public Result<string> AsError()
{        
   return Result.Failure<string>(Error);
}
```

In all honesty, I think what you have is declarative and not trying to be magic. I would just stick with some helper (extension) methods if need be.

Comment: Thanks, good direction. I'm particularly wondering if there's a generic way, or if I would need to account for every possible combintation of `<T>` in the overloads/extensions.

Comment: Meaning, if I encounter 20 different combinations of types, I would end up with 20 overloads or operators to account for each?

Comment: @NoahStahl if you have 20 different types, then you are just best with what you have and let generics be generics. I.e explicitly supplying the generic params. `AsError<T>()` or what ever incarnation it is

Comment: Gotcha. It does work fine, admittedly this is chasing that last bit of concise code. :)

Comment: I would be curious to understand more why you mentioned implicit operators are "unexpected and misusing the language feature".

Comment: @NoahStahl This would be more of my opinion type thing. Its not declarative, and kind of mashing a type into another type. You would have to find the implementation to work out whats going on, and you get no exploration intelisense and help tips. But once again, this is just my personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
    public class Result<T>
    {
        public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public bool HasValue { get; protected set; } = true;
    }

    public class Result : Result<object>
    {
        public Result() { HasValue = false; }
    }

    public static class ResultFactory
    {
        public static Result<T> Success<T>(T value)
        {
            return new Result<T> { Succeeded = true, Value = value };
        }

        public static Result Success()
        {
            return new Result { Succeeded = true };
        }

        public static Result Failure(string error)
        {
            return new Result { Succeeded = false, Error = error };
        }
    }
```

This allows you not to have to "kludge" in a bool somewhere to to make it fit your pattern. Sure you are creating a null object, but that is more-or-less tucked away.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not clear on what the `HasValue` property is doing?

Comment: @NoahStahl - It is for the caller to know that no value has ever been associated with that `Result` -- So, for example, if you want to just set a `Success = true` with no value. The caller will know that it was intentional.